# Is it possible to see the database of MS Office Accounting 2009?

Tags: database, ms-access

Is there a way to access the database of Microsoft Office Accounting 2009? When I run reports it shows the data, but I need to see the underlying database.

I have tried searching the web to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

using MSSMLBIZ instance i login into SQL server. It has the database :)